# Unpredicted behavior of using non-unique IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

When people are saying that using identical id's for different DOM elements is wrong, I totally agree. I mean, there is no even something to discuss.

But what is actually meant by the phrase "if you will have several eponymous ids on the page, that doesn't guaranteed to work"?

What actually does not guaranteed to work? We can treat ID as a regular attribute, thus, we can find all divs that `document.querySelectorAll('[id="container"]')`. Accessing through getAttribute/setAttribute should work as well. If we are trying to fetch an element via `document.getElementById` - well, I haven't tested, but most probably selector engine will return first element it find traversing the tree. I can imagine this can not be guaranteed. What else?

CSS will work pretty fine - `#container {background-color: "red"}` will paint with red all found containers (or am I wrong). Can somebody show me where in standard spec such behaviour is not guaranteed?

So, what is actually not guaranteed? Once again, I do acknowledge the fact that using same IDs is wrong. Neither do I want discuss perfomance issues of applying id-heavy css rules. The question is about something which is quite similar to what C/C++ programmers call "unpredicted behavior".

**UPD:** If it sounds hard or even stupid for you, then well, just provide an examples of unpredictable ID related behavior in specific browser. At least, as for me, it is more useful answer than "well, anything is not guaranteed, how can not you get it!".

Comment: Some browsers will handle differently & in some selector scenarios you'll get a group and other cases you'll get the first or last one. ie unpredictable, ie not garanteed to work.

Comment: @Gats, with all due respect, some browsers will do it wrong in some cases is not the clearest answer. I'm not drunk at all, may is it is just my bad english.

Comment: Are you interested in how **specific** versions of **existing** browsers handle duplicate IDs? Or are you asking "what can generally go wrong if I do it"? The answer to the later question is clearly: "**Everything**".

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, OK, I'll try to edit question to sound more clearer.

Comment: As James says, if a browser refused to load your page due to duplicate ids, it would be within the spec and not wrong... and it wasn't an answer, just a comment... you're english is fine BTW :)

Answer (score 3):

An implementation would be within the spec if it refused completely to work with documents that contain duplicate ids, or ignored the multiply-used id in *all* of the elements that claim it, or returned a *random* of the elements from `getElementById`. It could even be a different random element in each call.

> Can somebody show me where in standard spec such behaviour is not guaranteed?

That's not how it works. If it's not guaranteed, then *everywhere* in the spec is where it's not guaranteed. It's only guaranteed if somewhere in the spec there's an explicit guarantee you can point to. Otherwise, there's no guarantee in the spec, which means that it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Implementation of what? CSS egnine, JS, xpath selectors, xslt engine - all of them?Which exactly spec we are talking about? Does it mean, for example, that css selector treats #container selector not like an alias for id="container", but adds some other limitations?

Comment: If you can find _any_ spec that guarantees it will work, then it is guaranteed by that spec. If you cannot, then you have no guarantee. The burden of proof that you have a guarantee is on you. It's not up to anyone else to prove to you that you haven't.

Comment: I think Hennings point is that, if id's are not unique, anything can happen. A producer of a browser, for example, is bound by the spec such that their browser must behave in a defined way, provided that the page adheres to the spec. If the page does not, the browsers behavior is undefined. As such, it could do anything at all, and still be within spec. It could display nothing, it could close the browser, it could display a message saying, 'this page contains non-unique ids'... anything.

Answer (score 3):

The spec says that ID's are supposed to be unique.

That means that the browser itself has no obligation to implement code that can support multiple non-unquie IDs. It can assume when it builds the DOM model that ids are unique and are usable as keys. They may work in some browsers, today. But maybe tomorrow they won't. Just because they *happen* to function in the browsers you have tested, doesn't mean they will in future versions, or they behave as such in a different non-repeatable manner.

Maybe the first time you load a page on a monday document.getElementById might return the first element, if it's after 5pm on a tuesday and it's on an SSL site, then maybe document.getElementById throws an exception. Maybe a new release of firefox doesn't apply css attributes to anything past the first occurance of the id. Who knows. The browser developers don't *have to care*, that is what "not guaranteed to work" means.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle showing some selector quirks: http://jsfiddle.net/DmEmJ/

Quoth the spec:

> **id = name [CS]**
>
>       This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

If you want a non-unique handle, use classes.  That's what they are for.

Comment: "must be unique" and, for example," does not guaranteed to be accessible through DOM methods if there are non-unique divs" actually differ.

Comment: Actually, they don't.  Another quote, regarding getElementByID: _Returns the Element whose ID is given by elementId. If no such element exists, returns null. Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID._ [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId).  You might be able to get away with the attribute selector but the behavior will be inconsistent at best.  It would also reduce the maintainability of the code as new developers would need to be aware of the use of non-unique identifiers.