# jQuery get value of each A tag without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need you'r help..to get each A tag href value .

E.G:

```
<a id="#founditems" href="45S4#6#@5463&">press on me</a>
<a id="#founditems" href="ssdf#%dfd@@Df">press on me</a>
<a id="#founditems" href="ghfAS3#SDF%^f">press on me</a>
<a id="#founditems" href="DFGDF#%^SDFFG">press on me</a>
```

I want to get each value of A tag when i press on each of one of them.
This list coming from AJAX with PHP with foreach , now in my client side when i press on "press on me" i want to take his value and to do somthing with it .

So far i did :

```
$(document).on('click','#founditems',function(e){
            $('#founditems').each(function() {  
                alert($(this).attr('href'));

        });

  });
```

**The alert keep give only the first A href value.**

I am newbie at javascript/jquery anyone can help me ?

PS: If you got any better way to take this value , it will be nice to get advice..i prefer take this value with php, but i using AJAX to take this value from php file with foreach, so the page not refreshed.

Thanks.

Comment: ID's should be Unique.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unpredicted behavior of using non-unique IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092950/unpredicted-behavior-of-using-non-unique-ids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you want only clicked item's href

```
$(document).on('click','#founditems',function(e){
        var $this=$(this)

        alert($this.attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of #ID(founditems) change it to class attribute and you can loop it like following,

```
$('.founditems').each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

all the best.

Comment: Ok its working , but now when i press first "press me" it will alert me all the other a with the same classes , i want only each one will alert the one who i presses

Answer (score 0):

id is a unique value. you should select all a element by:

```
$('a')
```